# Should cycling through a list stop/pause at the end of the list?

Tags: interaction-design, lists

**Cycling through a list of items** is a common user interface design pattern.

For example:

- Browser address bar: hold <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> to scroll through the list of websites.
- On-screen keyboard: hold <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> to select a key.
- Operating system application switcher: hold keys to cycle through a list of all open windows or applications:

  - Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>
  - Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

---

After hitting the end of the list, the selection cursor is generally able to go back to the start. But should that next cycle occur immediately and seamlessly? Or after a pause or subsequent action?

This question concerns what should happen when you are **holding the key** and the list selection cursor **hits the end of the list**.

There are two frequently used behaviors:

- The cycle **stops or pauses** at the end of the list. Hold the key again, in either direction, to restart the cycle.
- The cycle seamlessly wraps around to the other side of the list and **continues cycling**.

---

These behaviors can be easily compared via the Mac and iOS application switchers:

When you **hold** <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>:

- macOS application switcher stops at the end of the list, until you manually restart it:

  [image: macOS app switcher]
- iOS application switcher (using an iPad external keyboard) wraps around and cycles continuously:

  [image: iOS app switcher]

---

Which behavior is preferable?

What are the advantages and disadvantages for seamless cycling vs. a stop/pause?

Comment: Was this question inspired by discussions of this on twitter over the last 36 hours?

Comment: Cycling through options indefinitely should not be used when there are a lot of options. If the end of the menu is visible on the screen, it may be usable.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on the number of elements that are being cycled and the purpose of the cycle.

In most cases with not a huge number of elements going seamless to the beginning is a life saver. For example the ⌘ Tab I am not even aware of the order of the apps until I have already started cycling so it is easy to go past the app that I was interested in so I seamlessly continue cycling to go back to it.

On longer lists it might come out as a pain to trying to reach the 20th element out of a 21 element list and accidentally going back to the top.